# I want to use Yii2 and Postgres. There will be JSONB columns in Postgres. How can I work in Yii2 with these columns

Tags: postgresql, yii2

Is there any possibility for simple work with these columns. That is, the ability to read write update delete individual data in JSONB. Perhaps there is an extension for Yii2

Answer (score 0):

All the features can be read in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) and i did use this [source](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-json) as well, but since the question is not very specific, I will just give a working example from my practice.

For example, we have a json `unique_users` field in which we store IDs of exceptional users who can access the entity of this model.

```
 public function rules(){
     return [
         ['unique_users', 'default', 'value' => []],
     ];
 }
```

Here is the part of my query involving this field:

```
$query = Model::find();
$query->where('(unique_users @> \'"' . Yii::$app->user->identity->id . '"\'::jsonb) or jsonb_array_length(unique_users)=0');
```